# How do I select a specific font for display for a particular set of Unicode codepoints in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, fonts

I am using: 
`GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 (i386-apple-darwin11.4.2, NS apple-appkit-1138.51) of 2013-05-27 on Celestra.local`

I can get Chinese characters to display, but they use a 'Song' font, the typeface of which is difficult to read (it's analogous to a serif-font). **How do I tell Emacs to select a specific face to display Chinese characters?** All characters that are ASCII are displayed in Inconsolata.

I looked at [EmacsWiki:FontSets](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontSets) and added this to my .emacs file:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-standard"
                  (cons (decode-char 'ucs #x4E00)
                        (decode-char 'ucs #x9FFF))
                  "-*-SimHei-*-*-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-iso10646-1")
```

but my Chinese characters are stilled displayed in the default fallback font.

Comment: I would try `M-x list-faces-display` and see if any of those look like the font you're unhappy with.  Once you know the name of the face / variable, you can change it to whatever you want in your .emacs file.

Comment: @lawlist That works, but it doesn't display the faces in the script ('han) that I want. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try "fontset-default" rather than "fontset-standard", as fontset-default will be the fallback for all fontsets that do not specify something more specific.

I would also use script names rather than a character range, but either will work:

`(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'han "SimHei-14")`

You may need to add other scripts such as `'cjk-misc` for full coverage.